Pathwise linearization of diffusion processes
Let $W$ be a standard $n$-dimensional Brownian motion, and $X$ the diffusion process given by the solution to the SDE
$$dX_t = \mu(X_t) \, dt + \sigma(X_t) \, dW_t,$$
with $\mu: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, $\sigma: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ Lipschitz continuous, and $\sigma$ uniformly elliptic.
Then is it true that for all $t \geq 0$, almost surely we have
$$\limsup_{h \to 0^+} \left | \frac{X_{t + h} - X_t}{h^{1/2}} - \sigma (X_t) \left ( \frac{W_{t + h} - W_t}{h^{1/2}} \right ) \right | = 0?$$
Remark: The bound requested is quite sharp. To demonstrate its power, note that we would obtain as an immediate corollary the following:
Corollary: (Law of iterated logarithm for diffusion processes)
Almost surely, for all $t \geq 0$, we have
$$\limsup_{h \to 0_+} \frac{X_{t+h} - X_t}{\sqrt{2h \log \log \frac{1}{h}}} = -\liminf_{h \to 0_+} \frac{X_{t+h} - X_t}{\sqrt{2h \log \log \frac{1}{h}}} = |\sigma(X_t)|.$$

@NateRiver I agree that it is nice to document answers (and an encouraged policy) but maybe next time give a gap of a couple of days for other people to try to answer it first. That way it starts a nice conversation and others can contribute new ideas that perhaps you didn't already know.

@ThomasKojar Makes sense, I will do something more interactive like that next time.

@NateRiver just a reminder that those 'site rules' are Stack Exchange boilerplate rules, the social norms on MathOverflow tend away from asking with the intent to answer one's own question. If it turns someone asks a question and later figures it out, and no one has satisfactorily answered, then of course giving the answer is ok.

@NateRiver Fair enough regarding the site rules, I wasn't aware of that. (I still don't think it's a great use of the site though.) No idea what you're referring to with that 'disdain / dislike' aside.

@MartinHairer Ah.. just the phrasing of your comments. But maybe I am reading too much into it.

@NateRiver however, this question does seem to fit better in MSE. I might be wrong but the MO posts are usually more towards questions that are on the edge of being open problems or directly about open problems. This question seems to be a type of question found in standard textbooks on stochastic processes similar to others often posted on MSE. So I would agree that generally it is better to post more standard questions on MSE (especially the self-answered ones) and then if nobody answers for a week or so, you can try to transfer it here too. There are many experts on MSE too.

@ThomasKojar As the bound implies immediately a pretty nice law of iterated logarithm for diffusion processes (two line proof), I think it is a pretty POWERFUL bound. But maybe you disagree on the power level of the bound. If enough people feel the bound is insufficiently sharp, we may migrate it to MSE. I am okay with that. I will let the community decide.

@NateRiver MO is not really the place to promote results regardless of importance. Also, I am just saying that it seems to me that MO is generally more about semi-close or directly about open problems. The self-answered questions might better fit on MSE. And for more questions that might be answerable by standard techniques, you can also first try MSE for a week or so.

@ThomasKojar I am not really promoting the result, I asked it myself on the day it was posted. I just happened to solve it also around the same time, so I decided to write it up…

In any case, I am fine with any decision you wish to make on the post.

I have cleaned up some comments, since the discussion has addressed the main point in a collegial way.

This is true. We need the following result, essentially proven in this post.
Proposition: (Linearization of diffusion process)
With $X$ as in the problem statement, we have
$$ \mathbb E \left [\frac{\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |X_t - x - \sigma(X_0) W_t|}{\sqrt T} \right ] = O(\sqrt T)$$
as $T \to 0^+$.
Proof of main theorem: We aim to deduce this from the above proposition. The idea will be to apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma along a sparse enough subsequence, but not too sparse so that we do not lose control of the difference quotients.
To this end, let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Consider the sequence $t_n := \frac{1}{n^3}$. By the proposition and the Markov inequality, there exists some $C, N> 0$  such that for all $n \geq N$,
$$\mathbb P \left ( \frac{\sup_{0 \leq t \leq {t_n}} |X_{t_n} - x - \sigma(X_0) W_{t_n}|}{\sqrt {t_{n+1}}} \geq \varepsilon \right )$$
$$= \mathbb P \left (\frac{\sup_{0 \leq t \leq {t_n}} |X_{t_n} - x - \sigma(X_0) W_{t_n}|}{\sqrt {t_{n}}} \geq \varepsilon \sqrt \frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}\right )$$
$$ \leq  \frac{C}{\varepsilon}\sqrt \frac{t^2_{n}}{t_{n+1}}.$$
Since $\frac{t_n}{t_{n+1}} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, we conclude that for all  large enough $n$,
$$\mathbb P \left (\frac{\sup_{0 \leq t \leq {t_n}} |X_{t_n} - x - \sigma(X_0) W_{t_n}|}{\sqrt {t_{n+1}}} \geq \varepsilon \right ) \leq \frac{C}{\varepsilon}  \sqrt t_n,$$
with a different constant $C$. Recalling that $t_n := \frac{1}{n^3}$, we see that the RHS is summable in $n$, and so $\mathbb P (\limsup_{n} E_{n, \varepsilon}) = 0$, where $E_{n, \varepsilon}$ denotes the event that $\frac{\sup_{0 \leq t \leq {t_n}} |X_{t_n} - x - \sigma(X_0) W_{t_n}|}{\sqrt {t_{n+1}}} \geq \varepsilon$.
To conclude, we note that the event $ \{ \limsup_{h \to 0^+}| \frac{X_h - x - \sigma(X_0) W_h}{h^{1/2}} | > 0 \}$ is contained within the union $\bigcup_{m = 1}^\infty \limsup_n E_{n, 1/m}$ which has probability $0$. Thus
$$\limsup_{h \to 0^+} \left | \frac{X_h - x - \sigma(X_0) W_h}{h^{1/2}} \right | = 0$$
almost surely, as claimed.
